# xml parsing error, using php's asxml()

Tags: php, error-handling, xml-parsing

```
$file = simplexml_load_file($url); {


    foreach($file->entry as $post) {


    $row = simplexml_load_string($post->asXML()); // after adding this line, i get error message

    $links = $row->xpath('//link[@rel="alternate" and @type="text/html"]');
    echo (string) $post->title;
    echo (string) $links[0]['href'];
```

I use this script to parse atom feed. At first didn't work because it couldn't pass the link's href attribute properly. I added `$row` and even though it worked, it gives an error : "namespace prefix gd for etag on entry is not defined". I'm searching this for hours, can't find a solution. I was so close.

Answer (score 0):

The line `$row = simplexml_load_string($post->asXML());`, if it worked, would be a long-winded way of writing `$row = $post`. `->asXML()` and `simplexml_load_string` perform the opposite action to each other so you'd get back the same object you started with.

I think the reason it's behaving strangely in your case is that your XML document is using "namespaces", and the fragment of XML produced by `$post->asXML()` doesn't quite work as an XML document on its own.

I suspect that the original problem you had, which this line seemed to magically fix, was also with namespaces, as XPath is rather sensitive to them. Look up examples of using `registerXPathNamespace` and see if they solve your problem. If not, feel free to post a follow-up question showing your original problem, and including a sample of the XML you're processing.